# Conseguir url desde el direccionamiento de otra url

Tags: api, url, mercadolibre

Estoy intentando utilizar la api de mercado libre, y estoy teniendo un millon de problemas, ya que es la primera vez que me comunico con apis.

La cuestion que mercado libre te proporciona una sdk, en donde tenes clases meli.

Meli m=new Meli(8031175177076953L,"GwOHbDRJaYhnkFTM52GBzyQPVE6l2L4j");
En esta linea creamos la instancia de meli con un usuario valido

String redirectUrl =m.getAuthUrl("https://www.google.com.ar",Meli.AuthUrls.MLA);
Esto nos proporciona una url, que al acceder nos direcciona a otra donde se encuentra un codigo.
recibimos: https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=8031175177076953&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.ar

nos redirecciona:https://www.google.com.ar/?code=TG-5b0cb8cae4b0618b5d5dcb52-323536207

Lo que yo quiero es extraer de esa url "code=TG-5b0cb8cae4b0618b5d5dcb52-323536207"

Pero por ahora, para conseguirlo estoy accediendo a un navegador, pego la primer url y esta me direcciona a la nueva(en donde se encuentra el codigo). 
Necesito ayuda para poder generar el redireccionamiento desde codigo java y obtener la url sin tener que abrir el navegador y pegar la primer i
Url.

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo?, estoy trabado en el mismo punto. Gracias!

Comment: Fernando tengo el mismo problema que vos, pudiste solucionar el problema. porque la verdad que yo no puedo.

Comment: Hola me parece que esto ya lo hace la sdk de java de ml. Estuve revisando y veo que usa Jersey server.